# Ruby/CGI : How to detect if browser has requested to "STOP" operation and ignore request

Tags: ruby, httpwebrequest, cgi, webserver

I know that CGI and PHP scripts which take time have this problem of responding to USER requests (client side STOP request from browser) .

The request could be ignored in PHP via     ignore_user_abort() call . Is there a similar one for Ruby . I googled through few articles. I found out that we need to ignore SIG_INT to this process .

Is there is a proper way of doing this in CGI/Ruby or CGI in general

Answer (score 0):

Signals are handled using the `Signal` class (http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Signal.html).  You can ignore a signal like so:

```
Signal.trap("INT", "IGNORE")
```